# Update CountDownTimer with new Time - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, countdowntimer

I have a list of items that each have a time associated with it. I am trying have my timer go through each of the individual times one by one, so that the timer starts with the first item, counts down for the duration of its time, and when the first time is finished, the timer restarts with the second item's time.

Then repeat the process for the entire list.

I've tried numerous solutions, including the use of Threads/Runnables:

```
t = new Thread(){
       @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                    while(!workoutComplete){

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        workoutTime = DayWorkoutAdapter.workoutTime(j) * 60000;

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                workoutCountDownTimer = new IndividualCountDownTimerActivity(workoutTime, 1000);

                                currentWorkoutTimeVal.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        currentWorkoutTimeVal.setText(currentWorkoutTimeVal.getText());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
```

My CountDownTimer class is:

```
public class IndividualCountDownTimerActivity extends CountDownTimer{
    public IndividualCountDownTimerActivity(long startTime, long interval){
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        currentWorkoutTimeVal.setText("Workout time remaining " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if(!workoutComplete){
            currentWorkoutTimeVal.setText("Time for next workout!");
            j++;
        }
    }    
}
```

j is a global static variable that I am trying to update whenever a time has finished, and update it by j++ so that the next item in the list's time is used for the next "workoutTime" in the thread.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!